# Django cannot access context variable in Jinja template

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am unable to access the context variable in the Jinja HTML template. The following is the code.

view.py

```
class Home(views.APIView):
        renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
        
        def get(self,request):
            context = home(request)
            return Response(context)
        
        def get_template_names(self):
            #code to return the correct HTML template
            
            return [template_name]
```

The call "home(request)" in the "get" return a user object and dict. The following is the code

```
    def home(request):
            #lines of code
            context={"form":form,'questions':get_questions(),'user_ques':user_questions,'dates':dates}

            return context
```

Now, in the template I can access "questions" and dates variable. I cannot access the initial values of "form". The "form" is of type "forms.Form". When I debug, I can see the values are populated in the form variable, but when I check on the template side, they are "None". The same to "user_ques" is a dict of values, but on the template side its "{}".

Accessing the form variable in template like

```
 <label for="height" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{form.height_feet.initial}}</label>
```

Here height_feet is a defined in the form as

```
forms.IntegerField(min_value=4,max_value=8, required=True)
```

Attached is a screenshot of "form" variable in debug.
[image]

I am not sure what is happening. Any direction will help !

Comment: Can you add your template to the question?

Comment: Are you actually returning anything in your home() method? Your code is not showing any return statement.

Comment: @Rishi are you sure you passed initial values to the form/field? Can you show the initialisation of the form?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes "form = HealthInfoForm(initial=vars(rs[0]))" When i debug, I see the values under "form.initial". I have attached a screenshot

Comment: What does `vars(rs[0])` return?

Comment: It returns the db query table columns in dict format. These values are used to initialize the form variables.

Comment: What I have also found is my template data is not refreshing. I have included a simple variable in context "context={"form":form,"hello":7890,.....}". I made changes to the variable to see how my template responds, but it doesnt update the value.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at it issue. I was routing the call from the browser to the Django backend via "ajax" call. The response was given back the ajax call and I overlooked the response.